# SAPUI5 Gantt chart official example does not work

Tags: sapui5, gantt-chart

Dear SAPUI5 developers,

I want to use the Gantt chart of SAPUI5. I found just one example of Gantt Chart in the following link:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.gantt.sample.BasicGanttChart/preview

While the example works fine in their official website, I downloaded it and run inside of the WebIDE. But it throws the following error and its features like magnifier does not work.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: "-Infinity%" is of type string, expected sap.ui.core.CSSSize for property "selectionPanelSize" of Element sap.gantt.GanttChartWithTable#__xmlview0--ganttView(…)
```

I didn't change anything. So if you need to run the example to run it you can download the from the above link.

Also I am looking for a some tutorials about SAPUI5 Gantt Chart. But I have not yet found anything. If you can redirect me to some tutorial related to this feature I appreciate it.

As I understood this problem is not related to the controller. And even when I just load the XML view this error appears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can reconstruct the problem. You can get rid of that error if you supply a width to the view. But the controls still don't work. Perhaps because of the global IDs used in the controller to reference the controls in the view.

Comment: Sorry can you tell me to which element exactly you assigned the width? Actually I added it to the view but the error exist yet.

Comment: I added it to the BasicGanttChart.view.xml to the root mvc:View element: `width="800px"`

Comment: Exactly I added to the same element and the error exist yet,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.html, remove data-sap-ui-preload="async".
Hope it Helps.